# Not able to get output of "ps" command properly in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I have copied my script below. For the variable "userName" I am not getting expected output at correct place. The expected output is "pload", it is coming at the end. Any suggestion on this to get correctly ?

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
exp_internal 1
set timeout 30
set prompt {[$]}
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$server.com
expect "assword"
send $password\r
expect "$prompt"
expect *
send "ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\\n' | grep pload | uniq\r"
expect -re "(.*)\n"
sleep 20
set userName $expect_out(buffer)
puts "buffer:$userName end"
if { $userName eq "pload" } {
   send "sudo su - pload\r"
} else {
send "sudo su - pdev\r"
}
expect "assword"
send $password\r
expect "$prompt"
```

Below is log:

```
.
.
3997@fd0441a2:~\u0007\u001b[?1034h[f5103997@fd0441a2 ~]$"
expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " "
send: sending "ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq\r" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(.*)
' is '*
'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(.*)\n"? Gate "*\n"? gate=no
ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq

expect: does "ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(.*)\n"? Gate "*\n"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq\r\n"
buffer:ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq
 end
send: sending "sudo su - pdev\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword"? no
pload
[f5103997@fd0441a2 ~]$
expect: does "pload\r\n\u001b]0;f5103997@fd0441a2:~\u0007[f5103997@fd0441a2 ~]$ " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword"? no
sudo su - pdev
```

Comment: Example output of the `ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\n' | grep pload | uniq` command? Is it possible for the output to be multi-lined? Is it possible the output is empty? What do you want to get in the *userName* var?

Comment: @whjm, In the userName variable I want either pload or empty as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put some special chars around the command's output so it's a bit easier to write an expect RE. So try like this:

```
send "echo ==\">\$(ps aux | grep -v grep | tr ' ' '\\n' | grep pload | uniq)<\"==\r"
expect -re "==>(.*)<=="
set userName $expect_out(1,string)
#                        ^^^^^^^^
expect "$prompt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some edits to the expect code:

- Use `expect -re` and use patterns. For e.g., the prompt is set to `[f5103997@fd0441a2 ~]$` but the pattern to match is `[$]`. `expect -re {.*$]\s*}` is better, IMO.
- Change the default prompt to a known value (without any TCL special characters (like `$` and `[`) immediately after 1st login. The next set of commands should execute smoothly. I tried it, here's a snippet:

  ```
  expect -re {.*[pP]assword}
  send $password\r
  expect -re "$prompt"
  set newPrompt {MY_NEW_PROMPT> }
  send "export PS1=\"$newPrompt\"\r"
  expect -re ".*$newPrompt"
  send "\r"
  after 2000 ;# flush out the MOTD, etc.
  expect -re ".*$newPrompt"
  send "pwd\r"
  expect -re ".*$newPrompt"
  puts -->$expect_out(buffer)
  send "exit\r"
  ```

**Output:**

```
sharad@sharad:~$ expect sharad.expect
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sharad@localhost
sharad@localhost's password: 
export PS1="MY_NEW_PROMPT> "

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

175 packages can be updated.
4 updates are security updates.

export PS1="MY_NEW_PROMPT> "

Last login: Fri Dec 23 23:02:22 2016 from 127.0.0.1
sharad@sharad:~$ export PS1="MY_NEW_PROMPT> "
MY_NEW_PROMPT> 
MY_NEW_PROMPT> pwd
/home/sharad
MY_NEW_PROMPT> -->pwd
/home/sharad
MY_NEW_PROMPT> 
sharad@sharad:~$
```